# How to use hooks in custom plugins

Tags: docusaurus

I am trying to write a custom plugin for our Docusaurus site. I am able to wire up the custom component, but I cannot use hooks like `useState` or `useEffect`. The page crashes saying I'm using an invalid React hook.

[image]

I know its possible to use hooks because I see [other plugins](https://github.com/cmfcmf/docusaurus-search-local/blob/9d309412b4442e38f56758cd7b4d255089706f5d/packages/docusaurus-search-local/src/client/theme/SearchBar/HighlightSearchResults.tsx#L12-L16) doing it so I'm sure its a syntax problem somewhere.

Here's my code:

`index.ts`

```
import path from 'path'

module.exports = function () {
  return {
    name: 'docusaurus-theme-myorg-technology',

    getThemePath() {
      return path.resolve(__dirname, './theme')
    }
  };
};
```

`theme/index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import {CustomTOC} from './CustomTOC'

const WrappedTOC = (props: any) => {
    return (
      <CustomTOC {...props} />
    );
};

export default WrappedTOC;
```

`theme/CustomTOC.tsx`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TOC from '@theme-init/TOC';

export default function CustomTOC(props: any) {
  //const [tags, setTags] = useState<any[]>([]); <-- if I comment this out the page crashes

  return (
    <>
      <TOC {...props} />
      Hello world 
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Invalid hooks call" link to a doc page, that you should read carefully.

Most likely: you are using a different version of React for your component lib  that the one Docusaurus uses internally, and it leads to the React lib being used twice at runtime. Make sure the final project will only include one React version. You can for example use the exact same version that the one Docusaurus uses